# Facebook Video shows Facebook Header when embedded with JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I could not find a solution or documentation of that behaviour. Right now, when visiting a site with a facebook video on it with a mobile device, you get the facebook header in the iframe thats generated by the facebook sdk.

Is there any way to just show the video without the header?

The screenshot is from the official (german) facebook developer page.

[image: facebook header in facebook video]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/157171235015171/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe mentioned this seems to be an official bug in the facebook sdk...